# AWS SNS not send SMS, it makes a calling instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, call

I use both console and nodejs sdk to publish sns to send SMS message.
But what i received is a calling instead of text message.
I have researched but I not have the anwsers yet.
Please help!
Thanks so much!